# Generating index for large document with multiple included files

Tags: indexing, texniccenter

I am currently preparing a large document and want to include an index at the end. The individual chapters are included via `\input{}`. In these chapters I use the `\index{}`-command.

But even after hours of researching I cannot get it to generate the index:

```
Makeindex> Input index file minimalexample.idx not found.
Makeindex> Usage: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\makeindex.exe [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]
```

This is particularly confusing for me as a beginner because BibLaTeX can extract all citations from the input files without problems.

I use TeXnicCenter 2.0 Beta 1 (64-bit) as my editor and configured the output profile (for `makeindex`) as following:

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\makeindex.exe

"%tm.idx" -t "%tm.ilg" -o "%tm.ind"
```

My minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{main.tex}
\chapter{Test}
This is\index{is} an example\index{example}.
\end{filecontents}

%\makeindex 
%I use Texniccenter as my editor of choice and therefore 
%usually comment this out, but I am grateful if one could 
%provide a beginner-friendly commandline-walkthrough.

\begin{document}

\input{main}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

As I am still learning I would really appreciate any help and hints (also alternative packages).

Comment: You need the command `\makeindex` in your document. It tells latex to create an idx-file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: The demonstration paradox... by including \makeindex it works perfectly. Many thanks Ulrike.

Comment: Short note: It’s of course your choice, but chapters are in most cases better integrated with `\include`. See in LaTeX introductions for the differences to `\input`.